# AngularJS and google maps - working with polygons and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using a Google Maps plugin for AngularJS - http://angular-google-maps.org.
I'm trying to populate the map with polygons, so my HTML looks like that:

```
    <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">

         <polygon ng-repeat="poly in mapPolygons" path="poly.path" fill="poly.fill" stroke="poly.stroke"></polygon>

    </google-map>
```

Every time I try to populate my

```
$scope.mapPolygons = [{
        path: [{
            latitude: 32.22,
            longitude: 34.33
            },
            {
                latitude: 0.22,
                longitude: 0.33
            },
            {
                latitude: 32.22,
                longitude: 35.33
            },
            {
                latitude: 12.22,
                longitude: 12.33
            }],
        fill: {
            color: "#00bbf2",
            opacity: 0.8
        },
        stroke: {
            color: "#cacaca",
            weight: 5,
            opacity: 1.0
        }
    }];
```

I get the following error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and ended up just using the map object directly.

I bound the control method on the map directive to $scope.control. Then I have to wait til google maps fires the tilesloaded event. Then I can get the map object with.

```
gMap = $scope.control.getGMap();
```

After I have the map object I append polygons to it the non-Angular way.

This is really hacky and I would love to be able to use the polygon directive.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post your code so I can be sure that I understand the non-angular way? I'll continue search for an AnguarJS solution and will keep you update. Thanks again

Comment: So I found a temporary solution - upgrade to the development version on the angularjs-google-map: http://rawgithub.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/develop/dist/angular-google-maps.js